# multiple LocalForward in ssh_config

Tags: ssh, config

How do I do multiple port forwarding in a .ssh/config file? On the command line, I can do:

```
    ssh 10.0.0.10 -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 -L 8443:127.0.0.1:443
```

but when I do:

```
    LocalForward 8080 127.0.0.1:8080
    LocalForward 8443 127.0.0.1:443
```

in .ssh/config, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The `ssh_config` man page says:

> Multiple forwardings may be specified, and additional forwardings can be
>       given on the command line.  Only the superuser can forward privileged ports.

Perhaps the problem is with the permissions, are you using the same user for both commands?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `Host` was wrongly mentioned instead of `Hostname`.